# How to prove this sequence of functions is Cauchy for this metric?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $C([-1,1])$ be the set of all continuous functions from $[-1,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Let $d_1$ be a metric on this space defined as $$d_1(f,g) = \int_{-1}^{1} |f(t) - g(t)| dt. $$ Now consider for each $n \in \mathbb{N}_0$ the function $f_n \in C([-1,1])$ given by  $$ f_n(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & x \geq 1/n, \\ nx & -1/n < x < 1/n, \\ -1 & x \leq -1/n. \end{cases}$$

The course notes I'm studying says that it is easily shown that $d_1(f_n, f_m) \leq \frac{1}{n_0}$ for all $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}_0$ and for all $n,m \geq n_0$. This means $(f_n)_n$ is a Cauchy sequence.

My question now is: how does one show that $d_1(f_n,f_m) \leq 1/n_0$? I attempted to prove it as follows. We have $f_n(x) = f_m(x)$ outside the range $(-1/n, 1/n)$, so the integrals outside this range is zero. Let $n, m \geq n_0$. Then $$ d_1(f_n,f_m) = \int_{-1/n_0}^{1/n_0} | nx - mx| dx. $$ To do this integral I replaced $x$ by the by $1/n_0$ for the left term, and by $-1/n_0$ for the right term, to get the maximal estimate of the absolute value. This gives me $$ \int_{-1/n_0}^{1/n_0} \frac{n+m}{n_0} dx = \frac{(n+m)2}{n_0^2}. $$ Now I don't know how to proceed, since I already took $n, m \geq n_0$?

Comment: Assuming $n\neq m$, there will be a range where one function is constant and the other is not, which it does not look like you accounted for.

Comment: In fact, you may suppose that $m>n$ to bound $d_1(f_n,f_m)$. Note that $|f_n(x)|\leq 1$ for all $x$, hence $|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|\leq 2$ for all $x$.  By your remark, you get 
 $$d_1(f_n,f_m)=\int_{-1/n}^{1/n}|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|dx\leq \frac{4}{n}$$and this is sufficient to prove that $f_n$ is Cauchy.